# Unable to run app in Simulator : Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvelt.png)I am having trouble launching the simulator, I get the error code that the operation could not be completed.

Here is the error code I received from the console: 
I have already noticed that the CFBundleExecutable is missing or invalid, but since I am relatively new to Xcode, I was hoping to get some help and what I have to do to fix this issue.

```
Mar  6 17:24:51 Pauls-MBP installd[12084]: 0xb0093000 -[MIInstaller _bundlesAtURL:error:]: Failed to create bundle for file:///Users/Paul/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44B11D45-11C2-4FE3-9ACB-7BE3F82B3FE1/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LppSWd/extracted/Davy.app/ : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=11 "Bundle at path /Users/Paul/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44B11D45-11C2-4FE3-9ACB-7BE3F82B3FE1/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LppSWd/extracted/Davy.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=MissingBundleExecutable, FunctionName=-[MIExecutableBundle _validateWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Bundle at path /Users/Paul/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44B11D45-11C2-4FE3-9ACB-7BE3F82B3FE1/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LppSWd/extracted/Davy.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist, SourceFileLine=68}
Mar  6 17:24:51 Pauls-MBP CoreSimulatorBridge[12099]: 0xb0115000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=11 "Bundle at path /Users/Paul/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44B11D45-11C2-4FE3-9ACB-7BE3F82B3FE1/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LppSWd/extracted/Davy.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=MissingBundleExecutable, FunctionName=-[MIExecutableBundle _validateWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Bundle at path /Users/Paul/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44B11D45-11C2-4FE3-9ACB-7BE3F82B3FE1/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LppSWd/extracted/Davy.app has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist, SourceFileLine=68}
Mar  6 17:24:51 Pauls-MBP CoreSimulatorBridge[12099]: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
```

Comment: Show us your Info.plist.

Comment: I just did, link is in the description. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would recommend you to reset the iphone simulator, and do a all clear on the project (cmd+shift+k and derived data), another option is to recreate the project scheme, other than that, no ideas.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to `Reset Content & Settings` in simulator and also try cleaning your build folder in xCode using `cmd+shift+option+k`
You may also want to check the ***bundle identifier***.